# "Контроль за качеством" ,"контроль над качеством" или "контроль качества"?

Tags: лексика

"Контроль за качеством", "контроль над качеством" или "контроль качества"? Как правильно написать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Слово ***контроль*** употребляется со следующими предлогами:

1. контроль *за чем* и *над чем* – при отглагольных существительных;
2. контроль *за чем* – при существительных, обозначающих действие или признак;
3. контроль *над кем-чем* – при существительных абстрактных и одушевленных;
4. контроль *чего* – в официальной и профессионально-технической речи.

В вашем случае можно порекомендовать предлог *за* (в соответствии со 2-м пунктом: слово *качество* имеет значение признака) или *над* (в соотв. с 3-м: оно является абстрактным существительным). Однако и вариант с беспредложным управлением, как видим, не является неверным. Таким образом, все правы. :)

Comment: вот спасибо! теперь всё понятно!

Answer (score 0):

"Контроль за качеством" и "контроль качества".

Comment: нельзя ли обосновать? мне то тоже так кажется, но настаивают на "над качеством"